# Does DCT diagonalize the FD discretisation of the Laplacian with Neumann boundary conditions?

Tags: finite-difference, boundary-conditions, poisson, fourier-transform, laplacian

If one has the Poisson problem (assume $\int_{\Omega} f = 0$ and $\int_{\Omega} u = 0$):

\begin{alignat}{3}
\Delta u(x) &= f(x), &\quad&x\in\Omega \\
\partial_nu(x) &= 0, &\quad&x\in\partial\Omega,
\end{alignat}

then a standard approach is to discretise it using finite differences. For example in 1D we have:

\begin{equation}
    (\Delta u)_i \approx \frac{u_{i-1}-2u_i+u_{i+1}}{h^2}.
\end{equation}

Enforcing the Neumann boundary conditions one ends up with a system of the form:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\ 
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\ 
&&&\ldots&& \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1\\
0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ \ldots \\ u_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \\ \ldots \\ f_n \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I have seen (e.g. https://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/neumann-cosine/) the DCT being suggested as a solution for this problem. If I term the above matrix $L$, then as I understand it, the DCT matrix $V^T$ is supposed to diagonalize $L = V\Lambda V^T:$
\begin{align}
Lu&=f \\
V^TLu&=V^Tf \\
V^TV\Lambda V^T u &= V^Tf \\
V^T u &= \Lambda^{-1}V^T f \\
u &= V \Lambda^{-1} V^T f.
\end{align}
I know for instance that the DFT diagonalizes circulant matrices, however I wasn't aware that the DCT diagonalizes matrices of the above form. I found the following work on the structure of matrices that the discrete cosine and sine transforms diagonalize: ["Matrices diagonalized by the discrete cosine and discrete sine transforms"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313523901_Matrices_diagonalized_by_the_discrete_cosine_and_discrete_sine_transforms). I decided to verify that this is indeed the case. I took as an example:
\begin{equation}
L = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and used the form described in the paper to try and match it:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
t_0 & \sqrt{2}t_1 & t_2 \\
\sqrt{2}t_1 & t_0+t_2 & \sqrt{2}t_1 \\
t_2 & \sqrt{2}t_1 & t_0
\end{bmatrix}
\, \textrm{or} \, 
\begin{bmatrix}
t_0 & \sqrt{2}t_1 & \sqrt{2}t_2 \\
\sqrt{2}t_1 & t_0+t_2 & t_1+t_2 \\
\sqrt{2}t_2 & t_1+t_2 & t_0+t_1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

However neither of the described forms (corresponding to different types of DCT) can produce the above matrix, as $t_0=-1, t_2 = 0 \implies t_0+t_2 = -1 \ne -2$. Am I misunderstanding something?

In fact, since the DCT acts as if the signal had been mirrored, I would expect that it should be able to diagonalize any circulant matrix $C\in\mathbb{R}^{(n+2m)\times(n+2m)}, \, m\leq n$ that has been restricted as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 
\boldsymbol{0}_{n\times m} & \boldsymbol{I}_{n} & \boldsymbol{0}_{n\times m} \end{bmatrix}
C\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{A}_{m\times n} \\ \boldsymbol{I}_{n} \\ \boldsymbol{B}_{m\times n} \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

where $\boldsymbol{I}_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $\boldsymbol{A}_{m \times n}$ is the exchange matrix (ones on the antidiagonal) with its top $(n-m)$ rows removed, while $\boldsymbol{B}_{m \times n}$ is the exchange matrix with it bottom $(n-m)$ rows removed. Essentially the above acts as if the vector to be multiplied on the right was reflected on the boundaries for $m$ elements, e.g. $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ results in:
\begin{equation}
u = (v_m, \ldots, v_1, v_1, \ldots, v_n, v_n, \ldots, v_{n-m+1}),
\end{equation}
then the full $C$ is applied, and finally the extra elements are thrown away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "issue" seems to have been that there is a discrepancy between the used transforms. The DCT transforms discussed in the linked paper are orthogonal, i.e. $U^{-1}=U^T$, where the even one corresponds to DCT-I. The orthogonal DCT-I cannot diagonalize the Laplacian (with midpoint reflection, for more details see section 3 [in Strang's paper on DCT](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144598336745)). However the non-orthogonal version $V = D U D^{-1}, \, D=\operatorname{diag}(d)$ for a suitable $d$ would diagonalize the Laplacian with midpoint reflection.

Since the matrices considered in the paper have the form $U \Lambda U^T$ if I now require that $L = V\Lambda V^{-1}$ then this is equivalent to $ L = DUD^{-1}\Lambda D^{-1}U^TD$, but $\Sigma = D^{-1}\Lambda D^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix also, so the whole thing can be written as $D(U\Sigma U^T)D$. Since the structure of $U\Sigma U^T$ is given explicitly, all I need to do is multiply by $D$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} (d_1)^2 t_0 & (d_1d_2)\sqrt{2} t_1 & (d_1d_3) t_2 \\
(d_2d_1) \sqrt{2}t_1 & (d_2)^2 (t_0+t_2) & (d_1d_3)\sqrt{2} t_1 \\
(d_3d_1) t_2 & (d_3 d_2) \sqrt{2}t_1 & (d_3)^2 t_0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Then for $d_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \, d_2 = 1,\, d_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $t_0 = -2,\, t_1 = 1,\, t_2=0,$ I get the desired result. For arbitrary $n$ this extends with $d_1 = 2^{-0.5},\,d_2 = 1,\, \ldots,\, d_{n-1} = 1,\, d_n = 2^{-0.5}$ and $t_0 = -2,\, t_1 = 1,\, t_i = 0$. This rescaling corresponds to the standard non-orthogonal DCT-I transform (if it is additionally multiplied by the scalar $\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}$).

Consequently the diagonalization has the form for DCT-I:
\begin{align}
Lu &= f \\
V^{-1}V \Lambda V^{-1} u &= V^{-1} f \\
u &= V\Lambda^{-1}V^{-1} f.
\end{align}

It turns out that the unitary version of DCT-II:
\begin{equation}
U_{ij} = \frac{C_i}{\sqrt{N}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi i (j+\frac{1}{2})}{N}\right), \, C_1 = 1, \, C_i = \sqrt{2}, \, i\ne 1,
\end{equation}
also diagonalizes the matrix $L$ I was considering. The mismatch occurred because the authors of the ["Matrices diagonalized by the discrete cosine and discrete sine transforms"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313523901_Matrices_diagonalized_by_the_discrete_cosine_and_discrete_sine_transforms) paper use a unitary DCT-I matrix in their $n$ even case (the notation in that paper is a bit non-standard). I found a very easy to follow [write up by Strang](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144598336745) on this however. It also shows how other DCT types as well as DST types model different boundary conditions (and mixtures of those).

I also found more details on the structure of matrices diagonalized by different types of DCT transforms: [Diagonalizing properties of the discrete cosine transforms](http://www.ugr.es/%7Esegura/pdfdocs/ie3sp95.pdf)